# How can I use a single MIDI controller in multiple applications on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, midi

I have a [Korg nanoKONTROL2](http://www.korg.com/us/products/controllers/nanokontrol2/) (in case it makes a difference) and I'd like to use it in multiple applications at once - say, left 4 faders in one, right 4 faders in another one.

It's not a problem to map it in the respective applications, but a single application grabs the controller, which means it can't be used as input in any other.

Is this possible? Thanks!

edit: I've since looked into various MIDI utilities, like loopMIDI which provides a loopback device, or MIDI-OX, but none of them - or no combination of them - supports having multiple virtual outputs per physical device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, it actually was important that I had a Korg nanoKONTROL2 (I assumed the problem was general, with W7's MIDI capabilities).

The manual states that the default drivers installed upon connection don't allow the controller to be used in several applications simultaneously; however, the official driver does.

After installing the official driver, the device is no longer blocked in a single application.